# Difference between Stripe Checkout https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js and Elements https://js.stripe.com/v3/

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment to integrate with my system.
But i did not understand a difference between this 2 library.

It's seem use javascript to generate the form and pass the token to our server side.

```
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
data-amount="2000"
data-name="Stripe.com"
data-description="2 widgets"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-locale="auto"
data-zip-code="true">
</script>
```

And this is using with .net core

```
<script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
class="stripe-button"
      data-key="@Stripe.Value.PublishableKey"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-description="Sample Charge"
      data-amount="500">
</script>
```

With out checkout.js, we also use

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<div id="payment-request-button">
 <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
</div>
```

That mean i can also use this 2 to use.
And two of this script , i can handle crate token and custom, so what is the difference behavior of this 2 scripts.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 13):

There is no difference. You should use the URL listed on Stripe's [Checkout documentation page](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout): `https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js`.

EDIT: It's up to you to choose whether to use [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) to collect and tokenize customer payment data. Checkout is a pre-built form that is usable immediately. If you want to design your own custom payment form, you should use Elements instead.

Comment: Hello @Ywain , i edited the question. I can use different script to generate.
So what is script should i decide to use ?

Comment: Hello @Ywain, That means checkout.js is  an embedded tool that takes care of building an HTML form, validating user input, and securing your customers' card data, it's build base on js.stripe.com/js ? And if we want to custom depend on our requirement , we should use the original ?

Comment: I have a question tho, is it possible to use ApplePay with stripe Elements ?

Answer (score 5):

[From official documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart)

> The simplest way for you to securely collect and tokenize card information is with **[Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout)**.
>
> **Stripe.js and Elements:** If you’d prefer to have complete control over the look and feel of your payment form, you can make use of [Stripe.js and Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js), our pre-built UI components. Refer to our [Elements quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a difference
StripeCheckout does not support the Cards API (from what I can see)
StripeElements does support the older CardsAPI https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges
https://github.com/stripe-samples/card-payment-charges-api/
https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment

Also, it is not clear to me how using StripeCheckout one could make use of the [older Orders data model](https://stripe.com/docs/orders). However, StripeCheckout says that it works with receipt generation, shipping calculations, tax calculations etc.